# How do I contact crypto moderators?

Tags: support, moderators

I can't find a question on Cryptography Stack Exchange and I don't have enough rep on this account to post on their meta. So I was wondering how do you contact moderators?

I can't find a question that I posted on Crypto a few months ago and I've searched a lot. I was wondering if they deleted it (I may have posted it with another account) but they gave me one or two legitimate answers. It was about being new to cryptography and where to start.

Comment: How about posting here whatever you need help with?  Maybe I or other members of the Crypto.SE community can help you.  What was the topic of the question you posted?  What can you remember about it that might help others find it?  Can you remember keywords, topics, etc.?

Comment: I gave most of the information I know..and the help team was able to find it that way...

Comment: It was probably [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/11929/where-should-i-start-with-cryptography) I could only manage to salvage the link from [Google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:-3-caB-A6UkJ:crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature%3Fsort%3Dvotes%26pagesize%3D15+&cd=3&hl=nl&ct=clnk&gl=nl)

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I thought about using google cache but I forgot

Comment: If you posted *from this account* you can access all your deleted posts - in your questions tab scroll down and click on "deleted questions". See: [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184), [How do I view my old deleted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217169) or [Is it possible to get access to my deleted questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213894). Or from some per-site-metas: [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948) and ....

Comment: ... and [Is there any way to see my deleted questions or answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13948) (But if you lost the account which you used for posting the question, this does not help.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't really reach the moderators if you can't post on meta or flag a post.

However, there's a "contact us" link at the bottom of all pages on the site that goes to [the Community team at Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do). We can likely help you out. Or at the very least you're gonna reach and get a response from a real person.

Here's the direct link from Crypto SE for your convenience: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/contact.