# How do I view my old deleted questions?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I checked View `Deleted Recent Questions` but it's only showing some of my questions that are lately deleted. I'm sure I've had more questions deleted before but how do I find the link for them if I didn't save it anywhere?

Also, what does the layout look like for users with 10k to view a deleted question? Is there a tab for it? I doubt I could get 10k so I was just wondering.

Comment: There is always the [Data explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries)...

Comment: @Werner Link doesn't work :(

Comment: You can search the queries... but I'm not familiar with the type you may need. Details on the data structures and their meaning is available in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and Data Explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/168244).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. They're deleted; you generally don't delete things you want to keep around and use, right?

The "Deleted recent" list gives you [a window of time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile/185492#185492) during which you can regain access if you need to. If you're not undeleting them, after a while they'll disappear. If that's not something you're comfortable with... Well, don't delete them in the first place.

Comment: How long does a self-deleted post stick around?  Really deleted after 60 days?  Or just gone from that link?

Comment: Few things are ever *really* gone. 60 days after the post's creation date, it'll drop off that list.

Comment: "don't delete them in the first place" is not so good advice, given [some content](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2805/16495) is deleted in moderation, even if author consider it good and useful. Also, some people want their question to stay deleted, but can't afford it if they are ever to recover from question ban.

Comment: Oh I see. But I'm just wondering, is there a button to view deleted everyone's questions tab? This is a question for 10k+ users.

Comment: Nope. 10k users see deleted posts if they have a link, but they won't see them listed on anyone's profile.

Comment: @Molot To prevent an unrecoverable question or answer ban, I guess you have to check your lists of recently deleted questions and answers on each Stack Exchange site at least once a month. This way you can notice that a question or answer has been deleted so that you can improve and undelete it before it becomes lost forever and thus a permanent strike against your account.

Comment: As mentioned in the [answer linked in this your post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185491#185492) and also in the [recent V2Blast's answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217169#375131), the restriction to the post from the past 60 days has now been removed.

Answer (score 8):

Searching for `user:me is:q deleted:1` as a 10k user shows you your deleted questions- I guess at this point you're trusted to be grown up about your deleted posts.

You'd get something like this

[image]

As you can see (I edited this image for brevity), deleted questions are shown there.

Comment: The `user:me` is not required, it will always show you only your own deleted posts. Unless you're a moderator of course.

Comment: ah. I am, in places. Not here of course. On the other hand, I definitely know this works

Comment: This should be marked answer!

Comment: I will add (at least in a comment) a link to the feature request relevant to this: [Enable searching with deleted:1 for 10k users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145060). (It was marked status-completed [in December 2015](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/145060/5).)

Comment: TBH, both this and at least one of the comments has aged badly, in a good way :D

Answer (score 6):

Per [Catija's answer to the feature request "Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374184/335251), this is now possible:

> We've been slowly moving towards completing this request over the
> years and have made incremental improvements to allow users to see
> content of their own that was deleted. The **TL;DR here is that we
> have updated (as of 2022-01-12) the recently deleted questions/answers
> pages to show all deleted questions and answers.**
>
> Additional changes:
>
> - The word "recently" has been removed from all references to these pages, including urls.
> - The pages now show all of your deleted questions or answers. Paging included, when necessary.
> - These pages can now be referenced by `/users/deleted-answers/current` and
>   `/users/deleted-questions/current` (which will load the pages for the
>   currently logged-in user).
> - The [*Deleted Answers*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current)
>   page has gotten a major facelift, and is now showing post summaries
>   that are much more inline with our design framework than the old list
>   (it is using a Stacks
>   [`post-summary`](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/post-summary/),
>   including answer score, question title, tags, last action date, and
>   answer excerpt).

The "Deleted Questions" and "Deleted Answers" pages now display all of your deleted questions and answers, respectively, regardless of how old they are.

Answer (score 5):

To view deleted questions/answers one has to have links to them. In the present Stack Exchange this feature is not available to all, as you have mentioned.

But links can be found in inbox.

It can be painstaking to find an old question if there are really large number of pages of notifications in the inbox.

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks a lot